# How to show local notifiactions only when the screen gets unlocked with an Ionic Capacitor App

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

How to show local notifiactions only when the screen gets unlocked with an Ionic Capacitor App?

When looking at the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor/local-notifications) of the capacitor local notifications plugin, I could not find any option for that.

Answer (score 0):

Local notifications are used for using inside of your app while the app is open and running, it will not work the way you think. For what you described you need Push notifications.

Comment: Local Notifications can also be displayed without the app running. But they can only be set while the App is running.

Comment: No they cant... why are you asking the question then if you "think" you know the answer?

Comment: normally, local notifications are also shown on the locked screen. I would like to know if there is a way to only show them when the screen gets unlocked or is already unlocked but not on the locked screen.

How I know that local notifications also work when the app is not running? I have it currently implemented in two apps.